# load content from other page with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, reload

I have a WordPress site, which is based on posts, but I want to filter my post with ajax.

The tricky part is that, if I want to filter from lets say "cases" to "photography" I have two different templates for this.

I can manage this with a little php and change the_template_part, but that makes the page reload which I don't want to do.

I've been trying to do a ajax request to complete the filter function.

My .js

```
   $('a[rel="filter"]').click(function() {

        var filter = $(this).attr('id');

        $('.checked').removeClass('checked');
        $(this).parent().addClass('checked');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data: window.location = '#?filter=' + filter,
            success: function() {
                $('#content').children().fadeOut(549);
                $('#content').html(data).fadeIn(549);
            }
        });

        console.log('Filter ' + $(this).attr('id') + ' clicked');
    });
```

And this is the php to change the template_part in my Index.php

```
    $type = ($_GET['filter'] == '') ? 'projects' : $_GET['filter'];
    <?php 
       get_template_part($type); 
    ?>
```

## Can I achieve this or do I need to think this over?

This just return the actual address in plain text

```
    $('a[rel="filter"]').click(function() {

        var filter = $(this).attr('href');

        $('.checked').removeClass('checked');
        $(this).parent().addClass('checked');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            //url: 'url' + filter,
            data: {
                filter: filter
            },
            success: function(html) {
                $('#content').children().fadeOut(549);
                $('#content').html(filter).fadeIn(549);
                console.log(filter);
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('No can do')
            }
        });

        console.log('Filter ' + filter + ' clicked');
        return false;
    });
```

If I have 3 pages with different queries and templates which represent (Case, photography and motion), which on the frontpage I want to make filterable. I'm working on a one page site.

Comment: Something is definitely looking a bit odd in your `data: window.location = '#?filter=' + filter` line. First of all, this is the data you send, meaning the entire string. Second of all, what is the "=" doing there? You'd rather want to replace it with `data: { page: 'blah', filter: filter }`. Thirdly, it looks like you haven't supplied a "data" variable in your success callback. `success: function(data) {` would be correct.

Comment: I should add that the main reason that your page reloads, is probably due to a javascript error - try to check your javascript console for errors.

Comment: Hmm...Tried that and unfortunately that doesnt work either

Comment: What does your JS console tell you? And what does your network tab tell you (what parameters are you sending?)

Comment: The console returns nothing unfortunately. just returns -1

if I should do it in some other way, can I just return part of a page?

lets say the content inside its container, how would that look like?

Comment: Try to look into the jquery load ([link](http://api.jquery.com/load/)) function. There you can specify an anchor on what to load.

Answer (score 1):

Add return false at the end of click function.